# Porque o meu Menu não está funcionando?

Tags: batch, cmd, ms-dos

Estou criando um menuzinho em Batch para rodar um script de 1 linha que mescla todos os arquivos de texto em 1 apenas. Mas não entendo porque a rotina não está funcionando.

**Setup**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Batch**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código**

```
@echo off

:Menu

Echo.
Echo  1 - Combo Merger
Echo.

set /p op=Escolha uma op‡Æo: 

GOTO:eof

Echo.

if /i "%op%" == "1"(

copy *.txt Combinados.txt

goto Menu

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na linha onde tem `GOTO:eof` você está mandando o interpretador sair da execução.

Quando for fazer a verificação coloque um espaço depois da variável que precisa ser verificada. No lugar de `"%op%" == "1"(` coloque `"%op%" == "1" (`.

Segue código funcionando:

```
@echo off

:Menu

Echo.
Echo  1 - Combo Merger
Echo.

set /p op=Escolha uma op‡Æo: 

Echo.

if /i "%op%" == "1" (

copy *.txt Combinados.txt

goto Menu

)
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! :D

Comment: Está feito, amigo!